# Two different x-axes using charts.js and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a chart component for weather in React using chart.js. I want two different x-axes with the temp above the chart, and the times below the chart. The data is correct in how I want it, I just want to use two different labels along the top and the bottom of the x-axes. How would I do this?

```js
import React from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

class WeatherOverview extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {
        labels: [
          "15:00",
          "18:00",
          "21:00",
          "00:00",
          "03:00",
          "06:00",
          "09:00",
          "12:00",
        ], //time
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [18, 19, 18, 16, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18], //temp
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        <Line
          data={this.state.chartData}
          options={{
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: 13, // lowest from data minus 2/3
                    display: false,
                  },
                },
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                  },
                },
                { position: "top" },
              ],
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WeatherOverview;
```

I want something like the google weather widget -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach:

```
var chartData = {
    labels: ['15:00', '18:00', '21:00', '00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00'],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "#FFF5D7",
            strokeColor: "#FFCC01",
            data: [18, 19, 18, 16, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData, {
    scaleOverride : true,
    scaleSteps : 10,
    scaleStepWidth : 3,
    scaleStartValue : 0,
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.points.forEach(function (points) {
                ctx.fillText(points.value, points.x, 20);
            });
        })
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MartinGK/u4Lr8gzw/31/

Maybe it will help you get started.

I recommend to continue reading [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

To match the Google Weather example with values floating over data points, what you really need is a plugin like [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app).

Install it via npm:

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels --save
```

Import:

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
```

And include it in your `options` object:

```
plugins: {
   datalabels: {
      display: true
   }
}
```

This will add data labels on top of your data points.  See the [documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/options.html) for further information on how to customize the data labels.

I've made your chart look like the Google Weather chart with a couple other changes.  Here's a full example using your data:

[image: Google Weather-like chart using Chart.js]

Some of the changes I made include:

- Added datalabels plugin
- Set colors accordingly
- Set `pointRadius` to 0 on your dataset
- Removed your extra X axis
- On each axis, set `drawBorder: false` and `tickMarkLength: 0`

```js
{
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['15:00', '18:00', '21:00', '00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00'], //time
    datasets: [{
      data: [18, 19, 18, 16, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18], //temp
      backgroundColor: '#fff5cc',
      borderColor: '#fc0',
      pointRadius: 0,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawBorder: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0,
        },
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 13, // lowest from data minus 2/3
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
          drawBorder: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0,
        },
        ticks: {
          fontColor: '#bababa',
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 20
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        align: 'top',
        color: '#bababa',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        display: true,
      },
    },
  }
}
```